# Flutter Dark Mode Icon Color

Tags: flutter, darkmode

I have set up Theme Data for Dark mode and my toolbar is giving me this random green color. Can someone tell me what this is called in my Theme Data?

I have played around with all sorts and still can't figure it out

[image]

Comment: This color is tealAccent.

Comment: this looks like it's part of your keyboard, if that's the case, you can't change the color for these specific icons from your flutter app, but you can only choose if the keyboard is light or dark using the `keyboardAppearance` variable, meaning if you want your keyboard to be light you should add this to your `TextField` :
`keyboardAppearance: Brightness.light`

Comment: Sorry I was more after the Theme Name of Bold, Italic etc. IE "AccentColor". Do you know what that would be?